# How can one UI Bootstrap DatePicker update several controllers?

Tags: angularjs

I am new to Angular JS and I suspect that the answer is to use a factory, but that is beyond my current ability.

Could I `$scope.$watch()` in my datepicker's controller and, when the value changes, set a `$rootscope` variable and have the other controllers `$rootscope.$watch()` that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your hunch is absolutely correct and it's the cleanest way that comes to mind:

```
app.service("dateService",function(){
  var selectedDate=null;
  return {
           getSelectedDate:function(){
             return selectedDate;
           },
           setSelectedDate:function(date){
             selectedDate=date;
           },
  };
})
```

and in your controllers:

```
app.controller("ctrl1",function($scope,dateService){
  $scope.$watch("dt",function(date){
    if(date){
      dateService.setSelectedDate(date);
    }
  },true);
});

app.controller("ctrl2",function($scope,dateService){
  $scope.$watch(dateService.getSelectedDate,function(date){
    $scope.dateFromTheOtherController=date;
  },true);
});
```